# How to draw a complicated smooth curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, curve-fitting

I want to make each of the bending very smooth. Only criterion to draw the curve is that it starts from (1,2.5) and ends at (1,2.75). No equation of the curve given. I failed to do that. Please help.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=13mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
     \begin{axis}[name=MyAxis,grid=major,grid style=dotted , xmin=0, xmax=12, ymin=0, ymax=5,
          xlabel=$x\rightarrow$, ylabel={$y \rightarrow$}, 
                  %xtick = {0,.3479,1},  xticklabels = {,$x_1$,},
                    %ytick = {0,0.015,0.0414,.4}, yticklabels={,,,},  %yticklabels=\empty,
         scale=1, restrict y to domain=0:5,clip=false]
    \draw  (1,0) -- (1,3);
    \addplot[color=red,smooth,thick,-] coordinates  {
    (1,2.5) (.3,2) (1,.8) (5,0.5) (7,.75) (7.75,1.15) (8.25,1.75)  (8,2.5) (7,3) (5,3.2) (3.75,3.15) (2.5,3) (1,2.75)};
            \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Considering you're giving coordinates and not an equation, your curve is already quite smooth. I mean, no amount of smoothing will change a sharp turn because a coordinate is in a non-convenient position for the path to turn gracefully "in time".

Comment: @Alenanno Is there any other way to get such (but much smooth) curve if the equation of the curve unknown.

Comment: @Alenanno: The curve can change at any "convenient" place as long as it passes through the given coordinates. This is the purpose of Hobby's algorithm implemented in the `hobby` package.

Answer (score 1):

You could `\draw[color=red] plot [smooth cycle]`  for a better result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=13mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,declare function={f(\x)=(10.5-\x)/(10.5);}]
 \begin{axis}[name=MyAxis,grid=major,grid style=dotted , xmin=0, xmax=12, ymin=0, ymax=5,
          xlabel=$x\rightarrow$, ylabel={$y \rightarrow$}, 
                  %xtick = {0,.3479,1},  xticklabels = {,$x_1$,},
                    %ytick = {0,0.015,0.0414,.4}, yticklabels={,,,},      %yticklabels=\empty,
         scale=1, restrict y to domain=0:5,clip=false]
    \draw  (1,0) -- (1,3);
    \draw[color=red] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {
(1,2.5) (.3,2) (1,.8) (5,0.5) (7,.75) (7.75,1.15) (8.25,1.75)  (8,2.5) (7,3) (5,3.2) (3.75,3.15) (2.5,3) (1,2.75)};
            \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result running in Gummi is:
[image]

Without the line, the curve is:
[image]

Original code posted by user1942348 without the line:
[image]

Comment: It looks like the one in the OP, can you superimpose them so we can see the difference?

Comment: I've added the screenshots without vertical line ruining the view.

Comment: @DJP Here the curves are not very smooth as expected. Also loop is not required.

Comment: `\draw plot [smooth] coordinates` gives the *exact* same curve as `\addplot[smooth] coordinates`. -Only difference is that you close the curve and that is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

Using `hobby`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=13mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, hobby}
%\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
     \begin{axis}[name=MyAxis,grid=major,grid style=dotted , xmin=0, xmax=12, ymin=0, ymax=5,
          xlabel=$x\rightarrow$, ylabel={$y \rightarrow$}, 
                  %xtick = {0,.3479,1},  xticklabels = {,$x_1$,},
                    %ytick = {0,0.015,0.0414,.4}, yticklabels={,,,},  %yticklabels=\empty,
         scale=1, restrict y to domain=0:5,clip=false]
    \draw  (1,0) -- (1,3);
    \draw[red, thick] (1,2.5)..(.3,2)..(1,.8)..(5,0.5)..(7,.75)..(7.75,1.15)..(8.25,1.75)..(8,2.5)..(7,3)..(5,3.2)..(3.75,3.15)..(2.5,3)..(1,2.75);
            \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Smooth curve]

**Edit:**

Cleaned up the code, and made the curve as a plot - `\addplot` with fewer points.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major, grid style=dotted, xmin=0, xmax=12, ymin=0, ymax=5, xlabel=$x\rightarrow$, ylabel={$y \rightarrow$}]
  \draw  (1,0) -- (1,3);
  \addplot[red, thick, smooth, hobby] coordinates  {(1,2.5) (.3,2) (1,.8) (5,0.5) (7,.75) (8.25,1.75) (5,3.2) (1,2.75)};    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Almost same smooth curve]